# Is INRIA going to add concurrency primitives to OCaml?

Tags: concurrency, functional-programming, ocaml

By "concurrency" I mean lightweight processes like Erlang's actors and concurrent GC aimed to make such a processes work smoothly.

It would be very cool if INRIA got rid of those drawbacks of the current OCaml implementation to make OCaml more prepared for the multicore future.

P.S. F# isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[no](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2002/11/64c14acb90cb14bedb2cacb73338fb15.en.html)

I cannot be more concise without reproducing his explanation. It speaks for itself. Yes, this is from 2002, but I haven't heard him sway on the issue, and from the text, it doesn't seem probable at all that he would back down from these goals.

For current developments on concurrent functional programming, possibly MPI solutions ([with ocaml bindings](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~xleroy/software.html#ocamlmpi)) might be a solution to your problem. Obviously this is not shared memory parallelism. There is also [concurrent ML](http://cml.cs.uchicago.edu/).

Comment: I'm not prepared to dig into the archives just now, but I'm sure there have been more recent threads where similar sentiments have been expressed. INRIA is focused on supported the OCaml language as is, not pushing forward with big new features like LWP or a concurrent runtime. Isn't that partly the point of Jon Harrop's HLVM?

Comment: ocaml4multicore is available (with limitations), see: http://www.algo-prog.info/ocmc/web/

Comment: Worth noting: what M. Leroy delivered that lecture to the OCaml list back in 2002, it was the case that SMP machines weren't nearly as common as they are today.  Still, it remains to be seen whether adding shared-memory parallelism to the OCaml runtime is a win over the more traditional approach to optimizing for SMP systems: fork/exec and interprocess communication.  It looks like INRIA has yet to make any announcements that its collective mind has changed.

Comment: @james woodyatt: "traditional approach to optimizing for SMP systems: fork/exec and interprocess communication". Such approaches only work well on distributed systems and, in particular, do not work well on multicores due to the shared memory bus and hierarchical caches.

Comment: @JonHarrop: Why does IPC not work well in that situation? Can't you still do shared memory IPC with Ocaml? Or couldn't you at least do so with bindings to a C library to do the setup?

Comment: @JosephGarvin: It just pushes the problem around. IPC generally means copying instead of shared memory, which is bad for multicore because copying means lots of unnecessary cache misses that end up contending for shared memory. You can share memory using IPC but it is out of reach of the GC so you either do manual memory management (not really OCaml) or you just use it as a buffer to copy data around (which still kills multicore performance). The only solution that works on a multicore is to exploit the hardware support for shared memory and, in particular, that means mutating in-place.

Comment: @JonHarrop: When one core writes to memory and then another core accesses that memory, it will lazily get that value over the bus (assuming it uses MESI, maybe that's an outdated assumption?). That's the expensive copy, right? That's going to happen regardless of whether you actually share the object or use it as a buffer -- soon as you access it you're triggering the traffic over the bus. So I'm not sure I see the down side of using it as a buffer, at least concurrency wise (still slower overall because you'll be making an extra intra cpu copy to bring it into the process's address space).

Comment: @Joseph: Consider the case of sharing a big `Set` used by two cores with a shared cache. With a shared heap, you have one copy of the set in the shared cache and both cores read from it. With message passing, you create a duplicate of the entire tree that uses twice as much memory and the two copies compete for space in the shared cache.

Comment: @JonHarrop: Ah, I'm more used to thinking about fast streams of lots of tiny messages that are quickly thrown away. But most desktop/server CPUs nowadays have both CPU local and shared caches, so the copies shouldn't compete for shared cache space, should they? On those CPUs I'm not actually sure what the protocol is for deciding when to move data between the shared cache and the local cache.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: If your messages are conveying any significant amount of data then naive message passing will deep copy that data when it could be passed by reference. From the point of view of the hardware, those copies are different data so they will compete for the same space in a shared cache. However, if you are passing many tiny messages then there is no difference as you say. I believe the local caches just replicate some of what is in the shared caches.

Comment: Unfortunately the list archive link is now broken.

Answer (score 2):

There is [J&oCaml](http://JoCaml.INRIA.Fr/), which is …

> [Objective Caml](http://Caml.INRIA.Fr/ocaml/) plus (&) the [join calculus](http://Moscova.INRIA.Fr/join/), that is, OCaml extended for concurrent and distributed programming.

Comment: But even with JoCaml you need to explicitly call fork if you want to use multiple cores.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [Jane Street](http://ocaml.janestreet.com) has funded a project for adding Concurrent GC to OCaml

- http://ocamlnews.blogspot.com/2008/04/ocaml-to-get-concurrent-garbage.html
- http://groups.google.com/group/fa.caml/msg/735752c0a7a0ba4c

Comment: That culminated in OCaml4Multicore but it is not very useful because allocation seriously damages scalability and allocation is practically unavoidable in OCaml due to the lack of value types.

Answer (score 0):

The [Thread module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Thread.html) in the standard library provides concurrency primitives, and has been around for quite a while. There are also [third](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/concurrent-programming-with-async.html) party [libraries](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/3.1.0/manual/) which provide higher-level / different concurrency APIs.

But it sounds like you are [conflating concurrency and parallelism](https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism).

OCaml of course doesn't get in the way of parallelism. You can run OCaml on thousands or millions of machines at the same time. There are even [MPI bindings](https://github.com/xavierleroy/ocamlmpi) to make it easier to program for massively parallel supercomputers. But the current reference OCaml implementation will not automatically parallelize concurrent programs, which I think is what you're really more interested in.

You may be interested in [Multicore OCaml](http://ocamllabs.io/doc/multicore.html) which provides better support for shared memory parallelism, as SMP computers have become quite prevalent over the last couple decades and it would be really nice to more easily optimize for them. They appear to be making slow but steady progress and trying to get it right.